# How can we print attachments from custom Visualforce Page?

Tags: attachment

I have a small requirement is there any way in which we can print Attachments in custom VF page store under any record(ex: Account.)

My Requirement is display a table and give a link to print. When user click on the link we should open a Popup of print module.

I am able to give user this
[image: Open View Options]

But they want this

[image: Print Popup.]

Can anyone please confirm if this is possible in Salesforce or using any third party tool or any Java WS(Means any way if possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer to [Print PDF directly from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239785/777642) might spare your users the second click. After a little testing, this works for me:

```
<apex:page >
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function printPDF(pdfId) {
        // Get iframed document
        var doc = document.getElementById(pdfId);
        doc = doc.contentWindow || doc;

        // Not ready to print?
        typeof doc.print === 'undefined' ?
            // Wait some
            setTimeout( function(){printPDF(pdfId)},1000) :
            // Ok, print
            doc.print();
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton onclick="printPDF('pdf');return false;" value="Print"/>
        <iframe src="/resource/1456133737000/example" id="pdf" style="display:none;"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Note:** In the above example I am referencing a pdf uploaded as a static resource.

### Attachents

Unfortunately, this won't work with **attachments**, since salesforce hosts them on a different (sub)domain, in my case:

`https://c.eu6.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=id`

whereas the page resides on:

`https://c.eu6.visual.force.com/apex/PrintPDF`

Since the page and the embedded / iframed content are not on the same domain, javascript cannot execute any functions of those contents.

Comment: let me check. Although i have tried it.

Comment: not working `doc.print = 'undefined'` is always undefined. or if i try `window.print();` then it will print blank pages.

Comment: In the above code, so long as `doc.print` is `undefined` it sets a new timeout. So, what exactly did you try?

Comment: i tried exactly same code.

Comment: @TusharSharma, I edited my answer to show a working example.

Comment: let me check.  here example are static resource or attachment? In my case i am using Attachment.

Comment: @TusharSharma, the problem why attachments don't work the same way is that they are on a different (sub)domain than pages and so your javascript cannot execute functions against the iframe or embedded contents.

Comment: @TusharSharma, one reason why I think salesforce puts attachments on a different domain than visualforce pages is to cut down on server load. This method would literally download attachments everytime you view a record. So that's really bad, performance-wise. Therefore, a manual workflow requires to first open the attachment and then print it form whatever ui displays it.

Comment: Yes  i am thinking same.